# Applying @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY) on field not working

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I'm very new to Spring Boot and having trouble where I am having the User model and I am using the same to sign up and return the response to user. While signing up, ofcourse, I need the password field and when returning the response about user, I don't need to return the password field, therefore, I tried using @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY), but I'm still getting the password field when i fetch the user details from db. What am I doing wrong?

```
package com.practice.todo.model;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import jakarta.persistence.*;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotBlank;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Pattern;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "name")
    private String name;
    @NotBlank
    @Column(name = "email", unique = true)
    @Pattern(regexp = "^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,}$", message = "Invalid Email Format")
    private String email;
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 8)
    @Column(name = "password")
    @JsonProperty(access = JsonProperty.Access.WRITE_ONLY)
    private String password;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User{" + "id=" + id + ", name='" + name + '\'' + ", email='" + email + '\'' + ", password='" + password + '\'' + '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I completely follow. Are you saying, because of your annotation, DB read will not read the column from the table? @JsonProperty is only for serialize/deserialize JSON to Java POJO. I has no impact on DB reads.

Comment: @bharathp According to my understanding, db read will ofcourse read all the columns but because of the annotation, after serialization, I should get back result without the password field. I maybe wrong, please correct me if I am.

Comment: So the annotation is only useful if you are converting an User object to JSON string. That is if you have User(1, "John", "someEmail", "securePassword") and you serialize it to JSON you will get {"id": 1, "name": "John", "email": "someEmail"}. But the annotation has no affect when you do a DB read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just checked your code and it works as expected. The `password` field is not included in the JSON string returned as a response to the REST call.

However it is still included in the log. This is because you are including it in the `toString()` method. Better remove it from there.

Comment: Thanks you very much. I was checking in the logs and could see the password field there so thought it will be included in the response. Indeed, my code is working fine.